# Spinner onItemSelected a Action should trigger in for getting data

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying this code

```
findUsStateOrMileSpinnerState.setOnItemSelectedListener(
  new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
         int i, long l) 
    { 
       spinnerState = findUsStateOrMileSpinnerState.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
       if(spinnerState.equalsIgnoreCase("State")){
           getDetailsState();
       }
       if(spinnerState == "Miles"){
            getDetailsMiles();              
       }    
    } 

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
       return;
    } 
  }
);
```

On some selected item it should call another listener.
Spinner is having Miles and State.
But it is not going through the if statement, am I doing something wrong.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the eqauls() method for comparing two strings in your code instead of == operator ?

```
if (spinnerState.equals("Miles") {
    getDetailsMiles();
    ...
}
```

Check this out plz : http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=221

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `getSelectedIndex()` instead of `getSelectedItem()`. You have to be sure you always get "State" and "Miles" at specified index.

Answer (score 0):

You should do string compare via `equals` and not `spinnerState == "Miles"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using equalsIgnoreCase or equals instead of using == to compare strings